# Awk stop processing in case of only head row is existed in the file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have one awk to process as below

```
awk 'FNR==1 && NR!=1 { while (/1Name/) getline; } 1 { print } ' *.test.final | sort -t $'\t' -k1,1 > test.out
```

This is combine multiple files which have extension .test.final.

each files has same format like below

test1.test.final

```
1Name    column1     column2
Test1_1      5          4
Test1_2      3          2
```

another file test2.test.final

```
1Name    column1     column2
Test2_1      2          4
Test2_2      3          2
```

So final results like below,

```
1Name    column1     column2
Test1_1      5          4
Test1_2      3          2
Test2_1      2          4
Test2_2      3          2
```

But some times it just stopped processing in case there is no data is existed in the file.

Like below,

test3.test.final

```
1Name    column1     column2
```

It is just stop and do not process

Anyone know why and how to fix this?
All files are tab delimited.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are overcomplicating the code by using a `while` and `getline`.

Just skip the header of the files when they are not the first one. On the rest of cases, print normally:

```
awk 'FNR==1 && NR!=1 {next} 1' *.test.final
```

Tested with all your `*.test.final` files and worked well:

```
$ awk 'FNR==1 && NR!=1 {next} 1' *.final
1Name    column1     column2
Test1_1      5          4
Test1_2      3          2
Test2_1      2          4
Test2_2      3          2
```